# jQuery Loop for continue after value < 4 start again with 1 in For Loop

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, for-loop

jQuery Loop for continue after value < 4  start again with 1 trying to make a slider using jQuery. but it is loading and not getting response.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('.slide:nth-child(2)').css('display','none');
$('.slide:nth-child(3)').css('display','none');
$('.slide:nth-child(4)').css('display','none');

    $('.list ul li:nth-child(1)').click(function(e){
        $('.list ul li:nth-child(2)').removeClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(2)').css('display','none');

        $('.list ul li:nth-child(3)').removeClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(3)').css('display','none');

        $('.list ul li:nth-child(4)').removeClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(4)').css('display','none');

        $('.list ul li:nth-child(1)').addClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(1)').fadeIn( 500, function(){
            $('.slide:nth-child(1)').css('display','block');
        });
    });

    $('.list ul li:nth-child(2)').click(function(e){
        $('.list ul li:nth-child(1)').removeClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(1)').css('display','none');

        $('.list ul li:nth-child(3)').removeClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(3)').css('display','none');

        $('.list ul li:nth-child(4)').removeClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(4)').css('display','none');

        $('.list ul li:nth-child(2)').addClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(2)').fadeIn( 500, function(){   
            $('.slide:nth-child(2)').css('display','block');
        });
    });

    $('.list ul li:nth-child(3)').click(function(e){
        $('.list ul li:nth-child(1)').removeClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(1)').css('display','none');

        $('.list ul li:nth-child(2)').removeClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(2)').css('display','none');

        $('.list ul li:nth-child(4)').removeClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(4)').css('display','none');

        $('.list ul li:nth-child(3)').addClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(3)').fadeIn( 500, function(){
            $('.slide:nth-child(3)').css('display','block');
        });
    });

    $('.list ul li:nth-child(4)').click(function(e){
        $('.list ul li:nth-child(1)').removeClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(1)').css('display','none');

        $('.list ul li:nth-child(2)').removeClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(2)').css('display','none');

        $('.list ul li:nth-child(3)').removeClass('active');    
        $('.slide:nth-child(3)').css('display','none');

        $('.list ul li:nth-child(4)').addClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(4)').fadeIn( 500, function(){
            $('.slide:nth-child(4)').css('display','block');
        });
    });
var timeset;

timeset = setTimeout(
    function() {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            if (i > 4) {
                var i = 1;
            }
            $('.list ul li:nth-child(' + i + ')').click();
        }
    }, 3000);
clearTimeout(timeset);
});
```

as you can see now I put my complete code here so you can view the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have called to a setTimeout() function and prevented the execution immediately by calling to clearTimeout() function.  So it will not work.

**EDIT**

After the the communicaton via comments, I came up with a solution. I guess, your requirement is to slide the images/divs in every 3 seconds.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('.slide:nth-child(2)').css('display','none');
    $('.slide:nth-child(3)').css('display', 'none');
    $('.slide:nth-child(4)').css('display', 'none');

    $('.list ul li:nth-child(1)').click(function (e) {
        $('.list ul li:nth-child(2)').removeClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(2)').css('display', 'none');

        $('.list ul li:nth-child(3)').removeClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(3)').css('display', 'none');

        $('.list ul li:nth-child(4)').removeClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(4)').css('display', 'none');

        $('.list ul li:nth-child(1)').addClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(1)').fadeIn(500, function () {
            $('.slide:nth-child(1)').css('display', 'block');
        });
    });

    $('.list ul li:nth-child(2)').click(function (e) {
        $('.list ul li:nth-child(1)').removeClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(1)').css('display', 'none');

        $('.list ul li:nth-child(3)').removeClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(3)').css('display', 'none');

        $('.list ul li:nth-child(4)').removeClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(4)').css('display', 'none');

        $('.list ul li:nth-child(2)').addClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(2)').fadeIn(500, function () {
            $('.slide:nth-child(2)').css('display', 'block');
        });
    });

    $('.list ul li:nth-child(3)').click(function (e) {
        $('.list ul li:nth-child(1)').removeClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(1)').css('display', 'none');

        $('.list ul li:nth-child(2)').removeClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(2)').css('display', 'none');

        $('.list ul li:nth-child(4)').removeClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(4)').css('display', 'none');

        $('.list ul li:nth-child(3)').addClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(3)').fadeIn(500, function () {
            $('.slide:nth-child(3)').css('display', 'block');
        });
    });

    $('.list ul li:nth-child(4)').click(function (e) {
        $('.list ul li:nth-child(1)').removeClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(1)').css('display', 'none');

        $('.list ul li:nth-child(2)').removeClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(2)').css('display', 'none');

        $('.list ul li:nth-child(3)').removeClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(3)').css('display', 'none');

        $('.list ul li:nth-child(4)').addClass('active');
        $('.slide:nth-child(4)').fadeIn(500, function () {
            $('.slide:nth-child(4)').css('display', 'block');
        });
    });

    // Starting to slide (in each 3 seconds)

    var seconds = 3; 
    var i = 1;

    setTimeout(function () {
        slide();
    }, seconds * 1000);

    function slide() {

        if (i > 4) {
            i = 1;
        }

        //console.log(i);
        $('.list ul li:nth-child(' + i + ')').click();
        i++;

        setTimeout(function () {
            slide();
        }, seconds * 1000);
    }
});
</script>
```

*(Please note that your code is not up to the standard because the same piece of codes are repeated there. Instead you should have used functions. I have only concentrated about the sliding part here as a solution for the question you have raised)*

.

**EDIT 2**

Ok, I have written a small piece of code to fulfill your requirement.

Please see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j68xmwy3/).

.

**EDIT 3**

Stopped the fade-in animation of the slide before hide it (when the new slide to be displayed).

Please see this updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j68xmwy3/1/).

Comment: If i remove `clearTimeout()` then it is stopping page to load and if page is load then getting disabled to reload

Comment: Can you please give me an example didn't get exactly what you said .

Comment: Please refer to this. https://api.jquery.com/ready/. By the way, your timeout function will not work if you clear the timeout.

Comment: If you can please share the full javascript code. So that, it will be to easy to understand the issue.

Comment: Yes I added in `.ready` function and now I updated my whole code here so that you can find the issue.

Comment: but as I want one more thing is that when I click on other slide then the number of slide which we set with `var i` should be automatically changed to the clicked slide.

Comment: Please see the "EDIT 2" part of my answer.

Comment: I had seen the EDIT 2 @asankasri but there is a problem I found that while we click on the numbers  1 2 3 4 I mean `<li>` it will display to div so the problem is that when one div is animated with fade effect and at that time you click on `<li>` it will show two divs.

Comment: Well, for that you have to call to stop() function beforehide it. Please see "EDIT 3" in my answer. JQuery .stop() : https://api.jquery.com/stop/